# How to destroy a ViewModel when user leave a screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I have a splash screen, when it is displayed, my app loading some startup data from server, after loading the data shows another screen.
For splash screen I create a ViewModel, but it stays in memory all the time. How to destroy it correctly?

Thank you for help!

```
@HiltViewModel
class SplashViewModel @Inject constructor (private val repository: Repository) {
....
}
```

```
@Composable
fun SplashScreen(vm: SplashViewModel) {
...
}
```

```
@Composable
fun Navigate() {
   val navController = rememberNavController()
   NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "splash") {
      composable("splash") {
         SplashScreen(vm = hiltViewModel())
      }

      composable("main") {
         MainScreen(...) // When shows MainScreen, SplashViewModel object still is in memory 
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: So where do you pop your `"splash"` screen? You haven't included your code you use to `navigate` to `"main"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your viewmodel stays in memory because your splash screen is your root destination, and as such it stays always on the stack as the bottom entry.

If you want your splash viewmodel to be automatically destroyed when you leave your splash screen you should  pop it from the backstack when you navigate to your main screen, using `popUpTo`.

Another option you could consider is to make your main screen the root destination and then navigate from that screen to splash if you are starting the app fresh.

Using `hiltViewModel` and scoping the viewmodel to the nav graph destination as you do will ensure the viewmodel is destroyed when the user leaves that screen, provided it's not in the backstack.

Answer (score 0):

It is not explicitly supported in Android as far as I know. However, you could create a method named `onViewModelCleared()` inside the viewmodel itself and pass null to all the nullable objects, and something lightweight to non-null objects.

Comment: This is entirely incorrect - the `NavHost` will automatically call the existing `onCleared()` method of every `ViewModel` created in a screen once that screen is popped off the back stack before removing that `ViewModel` from memory.

Comment: What I meant, was manual clearance. That is why I used the word "explicitly"

Answer (score 0):

When you create ViewModel by using function `viewModel<YourViewModel>()` or `hiltViewModel<YourViewModel>()`, created ViewModel associated with scope of local `ViewModelStoreOwner`.
`ViewModelStoreOwner` contains class to store ViewModels - `ViewModelStore`, where you can remove all models stored inside with function `clear()`.

One of the ways to destroy a ViewModel when user leave a screen, you can create your own `ViewModelStoreOwner`, associate created ViewModel with it, and call `viewModelStoreOwner.viewModelStore.clear()` in composable function `DisposableEffect()` inside leaving screen.

Example:

1.Create your own simple `ViewModelStoreOwner`:

```
val viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash = object : ViewModelStoreOwner {
    override val viewModelStore: ViewModelStore = ViewModelStore()
}
```

2.When creating ViewModel by using function `viewModel()`, pass `viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash` in the parameter `viewModelStoreOwner`:

```
val viewModel = viewModel<ScreenSplashViewModel>(
    initializer = {
        ScreenSplashViewModel(Repository())
    },
    viewModelStoreOwner = viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash,
    key = "ScreenSplashViewModel"
)
```

3.Pass `viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash` in parameters in your composable function `ScreenSplash()` and call `viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash.viewModelStore.clear()` inside composable function `DisposableEffect()`:

```
@Composable
fun ScreenSplash(
    viewModel: ScreenSplashViewModel,
    viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash: ViewModelStoreOwner
) {
    //Your code of screen

    DisposableEffect(key1 = Unit, effect = {
        onDispose {
            //Code inside will work as the last thing after leaving the screen
            viewModelStoreOwnerScreenSplash.viewModelStore.clear()
        }
    })
}
```

When user leave `ScreenSplash`, function `DispossableEffect()` will be called and viewModel will be cleared and destroyed.