# View Model not destroyed on back press in jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am aware there are many similar questions and I have gone through them, still my issue is not solved.

Minified example of my problem,
I have 2 composables `ScreenA` and `ScreenB`.
Both composables have separate viewmodels.
I am starting at screen A and navigating to screen B. On back button press, I expect the screen B view model to be destroyed. So when I navigate again to screen B, I want its viewmodel to be created again.

**ScreenA**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenA(
    screenViewModel: ScreenAViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) { 
  // Compose code
}
```

**ScreenB**

```
@Composable
fun ScreenB(
    screenViewModel: ScreenBViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) { 
  // Compose code
}
```

From [the Hilt and Jetpack Navigation Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation), my understanding is using `hiltViewModel()` should scope the viewmodel to the particular composable. I am not clear if there is some mistake there.

#### How I have verified that the view model is not destroyed?

Added a breakpoint in screen B viewmodel init block. It is reaching init only once when I navigate back and forth.

**Referred Questions**
[How to destroy a ViewModel when user leave a screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347794/how-to-destroy-a-viewmodel-when-user-leave-a-screen)
[How to share a viewmodel between two or more Jetpack composables inside a Compose NavGraph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68857820/how-to-share-a-viewmodel-between-two-or-more-jetpack-composables-inside-a-compos/68857871#68857871)
[Activity view model in Jetpack compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68971231/activity-view-model-in-jetpack-compose)
[Android Compose Navigation and ViewModel lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064105/android-compose-navigation-and-viewmodel-lifecycle)
[Different viewmodel for different composable functions inside same activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691725/different-viewmodel-for-different-composable-functions-inside-same-activity)

Sample repo with minimum reproducible code - https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/compose-navigation-sample

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scoping States in Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64955859/scoping-states-in-jetpack-compose)

Comment: Ofc we need a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [Here's mine](https://gist.github.com/PhilipDukhov/b72cd4c32c7ff8745d8c29b8f4a9c29c), works as expected, e.g. `init` is called each time the screen appears and a new date time is displayed. If it doesn't work for you, which Compose/Navigation versions are you using?

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, Clearly I was doing something wrong in my main project. I created a sample MVP project to share here. But it works as expected. I will dig deeper into my repo to understand more and update if I get the issue root cause. Thanks. 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was, I was using using `CompositionLocalProvider` incorrectly.

This was my initial code.

```
@Composable
fun MyNavGraph(
    activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel,
    viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner,
) {
    val navHostController = rememberNavController()
    val myNavActions = remember(navHostController) {
        MyNavActions(navHostController)
    }

    NavHost(
        navController = navHostController,
        startDestination = Screen.Home.route,
    ) {
        composable(
            route = Screen.Home.route,
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides viewModelStoreOwner
            ) {
                HomeScreen(
                    activityViewModel = activityViewModel,
                    navigateToSettings = {
                        myNavActions.navigateTo(
                            navBackStackEntry,
                            Screen.Settings.route,
                        )
                    },
                )
            }
        }
        composable(
            route = Screen.Settings.route,
        ) { navBackStackEntry ->
            CompositionLocalProvider(
                LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides viewModelStoreOwner
            ) {
                SettingsScreen(
                    activityViewModel = activityViewModel,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Removing

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides viewModelStoreOwner
)
```

fixed the scoping of the viewmodel to composable scope.

Sample repo with initial commit and fixed commit -
https://github.com/Abhimanyu14/compose-navigation-sample