# JetPack Compose Dispose View Model

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel, android-jetpack-navigation

With my navigation graph I have three composable views that all share the same view model **SellViewModel** as shown  and all the three views are interacting with the car object inside the sell view model

```
class SellViewModel : ViewModel() {

    var car = mutableStateOf(UsedCar())

    fun getMoldBrands() {...}
    fun getMoldSpecs() {...}
```

And my navigation graph :

```
@Composable()
fun NavGraph() {
    val navController = rememberNavController()
    val vm  = SellViewModel()

    NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = "splash") {
        composable("splash") { Splash(navController) }
        composable("home") { Home(navController) }
        sellGraph(navController, vm)

    }
}

fun NavGraphBuilder.sellGraph(navController: NavController , vm : SellViewModel) {

    navigation(startDestination = "mold_brands", route = "sell") {
        composable("mold_brands") { Brands(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
        composable("Mold_specs") { Specs(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
       composable("mold_images") { Images(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
    }
}
```

I noticed that when I navigate back to the home screen my sell view model is never destroyed or disposed. and when I navigate for example again to the Brands view the car object still have its previous properties, how can i dispose this view model when i back to the home screen

**Update** : I updated my sell graph like below

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.sellGraph(navController: NavController) {
    val vm  = SellViewModel()

    navigation(startDestination = "mold_brands", route = "sell") {
        composable("mold_brands") { Brands(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
        composable("mold_specs") { Specs(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
        composable("mold_images") { Images(nav = navController, vm = vm) }
}
```

And I use in navigation to the sell views with `popUpTo`

```
nav.navigate("sell"){
    popUpTo("home")
}
```

But the view model still in memory and never disposed !

Any ideas, help will be much appreciated

Comment: read this question it will may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68347794/how-to-destroy-a-viewmodel-when-user-leave-a-screen

Comment: i checked that question, it didn't work for my case

Answer (score 1):

SellViewModel will never destroyed from your code. Because, you initiated it inside fun NavGraphBuilder.sellGraph and this fun will never become unused state.

If you want your viewModel to be disposed when you navigate to other screen, you have to initiate the viewModel inside that composable like below.

```
@Composable
fun Brands(nav: NavController, viewModel: SellViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
  ...
}

or 


@Composable
fun Brands(nav: NavController) {
  val viewModel: SellViewModel = viewModel()
  ...
}
```

Comment: Yes indeed, my issue that i have a common object between my screens `car` its properties changed in each screen ,